# MySql order by case when array

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to know if there is more efficient way to write the loop of cases.

```
$search = "ORDER BY CASE WHEN created_by = :created_by THEN -1                                             
           WHEN cat_id = 24  THEN -1 
           WHEN cat_id = 26  THEN -1 
           ELSE created_at END LIMIT :limit, :perpage";
```

I wonder if

```
WHEN cat_id = 24  THEN -1 
WHEN cat_id = 26  THEN -1
```

could be

```
WHEN cat_id = IN(24,26) THEN -1
```

if not how can I go about it? Do I have to make some sort of a `for` loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's just two values then you can use `OR` operator, e.g.:

```
WHEN (cat_id = 24 or cat_id = 26)  THEN -1
```

If you need to compare with multiple values but they are not sequencial then you can use `IN` operator, e.g.

```
WHEN (cat_id IN (24, 26))  THEN -1
```

If the values are in range then you can use `BETWEEN`, e.g.:

```
WHEN (cat_id BETWEEN 21 and 30)  THEN -1
```